# Java: Initialization with class declaration

Tags: java

I have this code and the output is different from expected. Test t1 is already being overwritten but still keeping its initial value. Why is that happening?

```
public class Test2 {
        Test t1 = new Test(1);

        Test2(int i) {
            t1 = new Test(i);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
         Test2 t2 = new Test2(5);
         Test2 t3 = new Test2(15);
    }
}
class Test {
    Test(int x) {
        System.out.println("Constructor called " + x);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Constructor called 1
Constructor called 5
Constructor called 1
Constructor called 15
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: What do you mean by "but still keeping its initial value"?

Comment: Nothing is being overriden in your code.

Comment: I wasn't expecting "Constructor called 1"

Comment: What do you think `Test t1 = new Test(1);` should do then? What makes you think so?

Comment: @learningnewthings Why? You're constructing a new `Test` within `Test2`.

Comment: if I comment out the main methods lines "Test2 t2 = new Test2(5); Test2 t3 = new Test2(15);". Then the output is none.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You seem to expect your code to be equivalent to

```
public class Test2 {
        Test t1;

        Test2(int i) {
            t1 = new Test(i);
        }
    ...
}
```

Actually, it's equivalent to

```
public class Test2 {
        Test t1;

        Test2(int i) {
            t1 = new Test(1);
            t1 = new Test(i);
        }
    ...
}
```

The code in the constructor doesn't *replace* default initialization; instead, initializers run before the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class Test2 {
        Test t1 = new Test(1); // you are creating Test class twice with argument 1 so output will be 1.

        Test2(int i) {
            t1 = new Test(i); // i = 5 and 15 
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
         Test2 t2 = new Test2(5);   // Here you create 2 new instances so constructor called twice
         Test2 t3 = new Test2(15);
    }
}
class Test {
    Test(int x) {
        System.out.println("Constructor called " + x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question  **Why is that happening?**

Because every time you initialize **Test2**, its initialize **Test** twice. Because each time a class load, it loads with its all child. So whenever **Test2** class loads it loads and initialize the **Test** outside and inside of constructor.

That is why you are getting **Constructor called 1** also.

Answer (score 0):

You get those output because the order of execution goes like this:

```
class Test2{
    Test t1 = new Test1(1);     //Executed first

    public Test2(int i){
        t1 = new Test(i);    //Executed second    
    }
}
```

The next thing you need to know is constructor will be invoked when you use the `new` keyword. Hence the constructor in class `Test1` is invoked 4 times:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
     Test2 t2 = new Test2(5);    //Test1 constructor invoked twice here
     Test2 t3 = new Test2(15);   //Test1 constructor invoked twice here
}
```

---

Running `Test2 t2 = new Test2(5);` will invoke

```
new Test1(1);    //from: Test t1 = new Test1(1);
new Test(5);     //from: t1 = new Test(i);
```

Running `Test2 t3 = new Test2(15);` will invoke

```
new Test1(1);    //from: Test t1 = new Test1(1);
new Test(15);    //from: t1 = new Test(i);
```